# MongoDB - How to find where a document field contains a subdocument with a given name? (Example query and document included)

Tags: mongodb

Here I am trying to retrieve documents where the document contains a document DummyFoo, which in turn contains a document DummyBar?

As far as I can tell my syntax below is correct, but no results are returned, though I know that they exist. Have I structured my query incorrectly?

```
{ "DummyFoo" : { "$elemMatch" : { "DummyBar": { "$exists" : true } }}}
```

Below is an example of a document that I would expect to match:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5423d66ba077e6205cc9ecef"),
  "Title" : "Test 1234587611",
  "Subtitle" : "Test 1 Subtitle",
  "DummyFoo" : {
    "DummyDate" : "2014-09-25T09:46:35.6626303+01:00",
    "DummyBar" : {
      "Name" : "Test",
      "Number" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it correct or is it not? What does your document look like? AFAIK the only way other can tell you the right thing is by displaying the document you expect to match. ESP Candidates anyone?

Comment: That's a fair comment. I thought I might have structured the query badly. I have now added an example document. So, would you expect this query to match this document? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is specifically made for querying arrays.In this case, you have a nested json, which mongodb recognises as an [embedded document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#embedded-documents).

You can use the [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to query embedded documents.

```
 { "DummyFoo.DummyBar": { "$exists" : true }}
```

Comment: Correct. But embellishing "why" makes for a much better answer. Specifically, how about actually explaining why $elemMatch failed?

Comment: Why certainly would be of interest.

Comment: I think that [elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) works with array. If you change the structure with `"DummyFoo" : [{...}]`, the grx's query works

Comment: Sorry for not being clear on why it does not work. $elemMatch is specifically made for querying arrays. The dot notation is made for querying documents. I'll add this to the answer.