# Mongoose filter document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm learning mongodb with mongoose (normalized documents) and trying to understand how to fetch data accross referenced document

```
const employeeSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
});

const ContactSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    mobile: String,
    fax: String,
});

const DepartmentSchema = new Schema({
    contact: ContactSchema,
    title: String,
    director: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Employees',
    },
});

const ChannelSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
});

const StudentSchema = new Schema({
    channel: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Channels',
    },
    department: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Departments',
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
});

const Students = model('Students', StudentSchema);
const Departments = model('Departments', DepartmentSchema);
const Channels = model('Channels', ChannelSchema);
const Employees = model('Employees', employeeSchema);
```

How to achieve a query like below in mongoose

```
Students.find({ name: 'studentName' }); //Ok
Students.find({ channel: { name: 'channelName' } });
Students.find({ department: { director: { name: 'directorName' } } });
Students.find({ department: { contact: { email: 'emailDirector' } } });
```

The first line work as expected

Comment: Take a look at MongoDB aggregation pipelines which give you a powerful find() query.
you can use `$lookup` to apply queries on relations. check [MongoDB Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and [Mongoose Doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate) for more details.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26036545/2282634